# Match a string and replace remaning characters

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the server type from the hostname and replace the remaining characters with underscores so I can then use it with the `LIKE` pattern match in [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like)

My initial approach was something like this (this is the excepted output):

```
>>> host = 'webus01'
>>> location = 'us'
>>> parts = list(host.partition(location))
>>> parts
['web', 'us', '01']
>>> parts[1] = "_" * len(parts[1])
>>> parts[2] = "_" * len(parts[2])
>>> "".join(parts) + ".%"
'web____.%'
```

But this won't work if the `hostname` starts with or contains the `location` name:

```
>>> host = 'utilityit01'
>>> pod = 'it'
>>> parts = list(host.partition(location))
>>> parts
['utilityit01', '', '']
>>> parts[1] = "_" * len(parts[1])
>>> parts[2] = "_" * len(parts[2])
>>> "".join(parts) + ".%"
'utilityit01.%'
```

Then I though it will be better to use  `RegEx` for this to match only the `location` before digits.
The [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function seems to be a good candidate for this task but I'm not sure how to replace all characters instead of the match group as a whole:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'it\d+.*', '_', 'utilityit01a')
'utility_'
```

The output in this case should be: `utility_____.%`.

Comment: Perhaps `re.sub(r'(' + location + r'\d+.*)', lambda m: '_' * len(m.group(1)) + '.%', host)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
import re
print(re.sub(r'(it\d+.*)', lambda x: '_'*len(x.group(1))+".%" , 'utilityit01a'))
print(re.sub(r'(us\d+.*)', lambda x: '_'*len(x.group(1))+".%" , 'webus01'))
```

**Output:**

```
utility_____.%
web____.%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the substring that you want to replace first, and then replace it based on its length:

```
>>> import re
>>> host = 'utilityit01'
>>> substr = re.findall(r'it\d+.*', host)
>>> substr
['it01a']
>>> host.replace(substr[0], len(substr)*'_')
'utility_____'
```